# SQL Server 2008 R2 evaluation version expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade

I am really in a big trouble. I was using SQL Server 2008 R2 evaluation version and it expired today!

And I can't open Management Studio. The alert msg is:

> Evaluation period has expired. For information on how to upgrade your evaluation software please go to http://www.microsoft.com/sql/howtobuy

What can I do now? I don't have any copy of my database.

Please help me.

Comment: Was that a production system? If not, why worry? If yes, bad decision...

Comment: _What can I do now?_ - buy a license, maybe !?!??

Comment: You will likely have to buy a license if you want to gain access to the software. (In the future when evaluating software don't do any critical work with them as you will often lose it when the evaluation ends.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install developer edition which is [free](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/) and you can copy MDF files of old databases and attach [them](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/how-do-i-attach-a-database-in-sql-server)

Comment: is it will works? I mean does mdf file of 2008 will be worked on 2014?

Comment: yes ,it works..you can always go to a higher edition and restore it.But I am not sure whether you can install both enterprise and developer edition in same machines

Comment: So? after download completed, should I select installation or maintenance?

Comment: @sara _SQL Server Developer Edition is for **development and testing only, and not for production environments or for use with production data**._

Answer (score 1):

For information on how to upgrade your evaluation software please go to http://www.microsoft.com/sql/howtobuy